# SLIMFramework: split from one parameter as 3 parameters

Tags: php, slim

i have one service using slim framework. 
I'm calling URL listarTemperaturaMedia.php/R27229051234

here my PHP Code

```
$app->get('/{station}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    require("../ws/db.php");
    require("../ws/funcoes.php");
    $name = $args['station'];
    echo var_dump($args);
```

when I print the Array i got follow result

array(2) { ["station"]=> string(11) "R2722905123" ["data"]=> string(1) "4" }

why is Slim identifying that I have 2 parameters?

thanks a lot

Comment: `listarTemperaturaMedia.php` in the url makes no sense here. Do you have a index.php and a .htaccess file?

Comment: i don't have a Index.php file. i call lsitTemperaturaMedia.php there is the method implemented.

Comment: If you put `var_dump($args)` before `require`, does it print same output? By the way, maybe you can start from its documentation https://www.slimframework.com/docs/